# How to Store and Retrieve image in MongoDb using sailsjs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, bson, waterline

How to define the model for storing image for the following

```
var Person = {
  attributes: {
     firstName: 'STRING',
     lastName: 'STRING',
     age: 'INTEGER',
     image: 'STRING'
    }
};

module.exports = Person;
```

What should be the 'image' type and how to store image?

How to store and update image using model 'Person'?

Answer (score 4):

You could convert the image to a base64-encoded data-URL and store it in a `'STRING'` field. But keep in mind that MongoDB documents have a size restriction of 16MB. When you want to store larger images, you should consider to store them using [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/). In that case your `Person.image` field would be a `'STRING'` with the GridFS filename while the image data itself is stored on GridFS.

Comment: great answer to an interesting question, thanks this was helpful for me!

Comment: how to convert the image to a base64-encoded data-URL..??

Comment: @Darwesh That's a new question.